# Rails Updating an object with a hash produces undefined method stringify_keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a hash of fields stored in an instance variable called:

```
 @series_from_fred
```

When I pass this hash to

```
 Serial.create(@series_from_fred)
```

the new Serial (the model name) 'row' is created and the parameters within the hash map to the fields in the rows of the Serial model.

However, when I try to update an existing Serial via

```
 serial.update_attributes(@series_from_fred)
```

Note, 'serial' is part of a

```
 @serial.each do |serial|
```

I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in AdminsController#checkSerials

undefined method `stringify_keys' for #<Array:0x007fd1fe3085e0>
```

Any ideas?

This is what happens if I go into rails console and type 'Serial'

```
Serial(id: integer, series_name: string, realtime_start: string, 
realtime_end: string, title: string, observation_start: string, 
observation_end: string, frequency: string, frequency_short: string, 
units: string, units_short: string, seasonal_adjustment: string, 
seasonal_adjustment_short: string, last_updated: string, popularity: string, 
notes: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

Since I'm obtaining the data from an api at run time if I go into the rails console and type '@series_from_fred I'll get back 'nil'.  However, using logger.info(@series_from_fred.to_s) I'm able to "see" the value of @series_from_fred in the terminal output.  That output is:

```
[{"realtime_start"=>"2013-02-28", "realtime_end"=>"2013-02-28", 
"title"=>"Reserve Bank Credit - Securities Held Outright", 
"observation_start"=>"1989-03-22", "observation_end"=>"2013-02-20", 
"frequency"=>"Weekly, Ending Wednesday", "frequency_short"=>"W", 
"units"=>"Billions of Dollars", "units_short"=>"Bil. of $", 
"seasonal_adjustment"=>"Not Seasonally Adjusted", "seasonal_adjustment_short"=>"NSA", 
"last_updated"=>"2013-02-22 08:32:54-06", "popularity"=>"47", "notes"=>"The amount of 
securities held by Federal Reserve Banks. This quantity is the cumulative result of 
permanent open market operations: outright purchases or sales of securities, conducted 
by the Federal Reserve. Section 14 of the Federal Reserve Act defines the securities 
that the Federal Reserve is authorized to buy and sell.", "series_name"=>"WSECOUT"}]
```

Comment: what is checkSerials?

Comment: can you type "rails c" on your terminal and type "Serial" and post the ouput on your question?

Comment: @aromero checkSerials is a action in the Admins controller.

Comment: good, now can you output the instance variable "@series_from_fred" on the same console.

Comment: Use rails console and you will figure out what to do..http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=464320586932580&set=a.455517814479524.107202.455424531155519&type=1&theater

Comment: To whomever down voted my question, so I don't make the same mistake in the future, what about it makes it unworthy for inclusion?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your question, so I voted you up. Maybe it was Atlas? *shrug*

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not sure why

```
Serial.create(@series_from_fred) worked
```

and

```
serial.update_attributes(@series_from_fred)
```

would not work.  What I did to "fix" the issue was to convert the xml I was getting from the api to a hash via:

```
@series_from_fred = Hash.from_xml(series_responseHolder)
```

passing this to:

```
serial.update_attributes(@series_from_fred)
```

successfully updated the parameters for that record/object/row in the Serial model.